# Consistency of a linear system of $m$ equations with $n$ variables, $m>n$

Tags: linear-algebra

If the system of linear equations is $Ax=b$ and $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, $m>n$, it is impossible for the system to be consistent for all $b$.

Can this be justified by saying that the $RREF$ of matrix $A$ has to have a pivot position in every row, for the system to be consistent for any $b$ and that is impossible if $m>n$?